# wait until finish function - react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I will explain clearly my problem. I have a func who return json. Function's job is connect to db and bring some data. When i clicked button, i will do some action according to the func's return value. 
Before do that i print to console. Method have some logs too.

[image]

When i clicked button, orders of process like this..

- func is started..
- func is connect..
- **Result is : undefined**
- func is completed. data is {success:"00", data:"blablabla"}

Actually i have data but i cant wait till get result. How can i solve this?

Thanks guys

Comment: Checkout Promises and Async/await in JS, that will help you in resolving this issue on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `addUser` function works in an asynchronous way. Try this:

```
actions.addUser(Email, Password, Name, Surname)
  .then((res) => console.log("Result is : " + res);
```

or you can use async pattern

```
let result = await actions.addUser(Email, Password, Name, Surname);
console.log("Result is : " + result);
```

please note that `await` needs `async` function